# how to use node in react want to merge them

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have two app :

1. Todo App in react. [React Todo](https://github.com/mohsinbhaai/react-app)
2. Login and register in Node [Node Login App](https://github.com/mohsinbhaai/register-and-login-app)
   I want user first register and login the app. Then he can do Todo in that app.

Please help me out or suggest how to do. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON web services to communicate between the both apps and use JWT for creating stateless authentication between them.

Comment: hey, @jaswant can I merge that both app which I created? but doing little modification?

Answer (score 1):

This approach is not good but for your question, the best possible solution would be, this,

You can do one thing here.

Create [JWT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) tokens in [Node Login App](https://github.com/mohsinbhaai/register-and-login-app) and use that token in your [React Todo](https://github.com/mohsinbhaai/react-app) app using same **secret key**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey, @captain I agree approach is not good. can I merge that both app which I created? but doing little modification? is this compulsory to use JWT?

Comment: Yes, JWT will ensure the authenticated access to the app. and that's what you want correct?

Comment: I already have register and login app, just want to show that user can do TODO after login.

Comment: Yes, then just add the JWT authentication code and verification code and you are good to go. You can find the documentation on the https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken.